# Codeigniter: How to create variables common among all models?

Tags: codeigniter, models

I want to create variables to represent table names of database. (e.g `$tbl_users = 'xyz_users';`) Where do I define them so that they are accessible in all models?

Comment: You could define them as Constants within the `constants.php` config file? This file is one of the very first loaded by CI.

Comment: thanks Craig. Is there a way to have them as variables?

Comment: Just extend the CI model (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html), and define the variables. However, I would use the Constants file, like @saurabh2836 answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Define the name as above in `constant.php`

```
define('TBL_NAME','test');//test name corresponds to mysql table name
```

Model uses:

```
$this->db->get(TBL_NAME);
```

**This constant is available across the project.**